# django ImportError at /admin/ no module named todo

Tags: django, admin

I am following a tutorial on http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html to create a simple todo app. In one of the steps, I had to modify view to add an ability in 'admin' to mark tasks as done from that view. However I get the error ImportError at /admin/ no module named todo.

The error is not thrown from any particular line from the code so I do not know how to debug this. I am new to django. So I documented my error in my blog here: http://djangounchain.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/tutorial-8-todo-list-app/

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

You are registering your models to `AdminSite` in `todo/models.py` itself.

As per [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf), you need to create `admin.py` file inside your app for `admin.autodiscover()` to work properly.

> The last step in setting up the Django admin is to hook your AdminSite
>   instance into your URLconf. Do this by pointing a given URL at the
>   AdminSite.urls method.
>
> In this example, we register the default AdminSite instance
>   django.contrib.admin.site at the URL /admin/
>
> ```
> # urls.py
> from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
> from django.contrib import admin
>
> admin.autodiscover()
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
> )
> ```
>
> Above we used admin.autodiscover() to automatically load the
>   INSTALLED_APPS admin.py modules.